# Нарушаю ли я ООП, если я делаю ссылку к модели через presenter?

Tags: c#, ооп, теория

**Model.cs**

```
public string name { get; set;}
```

**Presenter.cs**

```
Model model = new Model();

public string name2 {
    get 
    {
        return model.name;
    }
    set
    {
        model.name = value;
    }
}
```

**View.cs**

```
Presenter presenter = new Presenter();

someTextBox.Text = presenter.name2;

void Send_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   presenter.name2 = someTextInputArea.Text;
}
```

Не нарушаю ли я таким образом ООП и почему?

Comment: я немного не понял выражение `нарушить ООП`. ООП - это объектно-ориентированное программирование. Если вы программируете на C#, то вы в любом случае используете объекты и ООП. Можно неправильно реализовать шаблон MVP или нарушить какие-то принципы ООП, например, SOLID, но нарушить ООП уж никак

Comment: Может вы имели в виду MVP а не ООП?